# Inverse function of FormatDateTime

Tags: delphi

I am looking for a function to reverse **any** string (`YYYYMDD`,`YY/MM/DD`,`YYMMDD`,...) created by the function [FormatDateTime](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=FormatDateTime) to datetime.

example

I have a string-date in format `YYYYMMDD`created by `FormatDateTime`

```
mydatestr:=FormatDateTime('YYYYMMDD',Mydate);
```

now how I can convert mydatestr to `DateTime` again?

UPDATE

these functions

```
function StrToDate(const S: string): TDateTime; overload;
function StrToDate(const S: string;
  const FormatSettings: TFormatSettings): TDateTime; overload;

function StrToDateTime(const S: string): TDateTime; overload;
function StrToDateTime(const S: string;
  const FormatSettings: TFormatSettings): TDateTime; overload;
```

do not support passing a string with the format to convert.

I am looking something like this

```
Mydatetime:=InvFormatDatetime('20091225','yyyymmdd');
```

or

```
Mydatetime:=InvFormatDatetime('20090108','yyyyddmm');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert an ISO 8601 string to a Delphi TDate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651829/how-do-i-convert-an-iso-8601-string-to-a-delphi-tdate)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is quite easy with existing solution, StrToDateFmt function in rxDateutil.pas unit from RX package, which can be downloaded here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/rxlib/

EDIT:

Mentioned above function and StrToDateFmt from rxDateutil.pas are doing exactly what you expect, converting string to datetime using specified string mask, the code is too large to be included as this unit contains also other date functions, some of them required for converting string to date.

Example of use:

```
Result := StrToDateFmtDef('MM/DD/YYYY', '11/11/2011', Now);
```

Comment: This function has also been ported to JVCL. It is in the "JvJCLUtils" Unit

Comment: Note that StrToDateFmt only does pure dates. It won't for example convert 'yyyymmddhhmmss'.

Comment: I still wonder why people use so frustrating format for expressing dates/times: '11/11/2011' - what is 11? Month, Day? or Day/Month? Yeah, you know the mask, but it's locale specific...Why not using a deterministic/strict standard, ISO8601 for example?

Answer (score 6):

***Note***: Unfortunately, as pointed out by Martien in this answer's comments, this solution will not work for cases where the date includes no date separator. However, I'm going to leave the answer up for anyone that may find it useful regardless.

I liked Tuncay's answer but there were a couple of problems with it. I'd have left a comment but I don't have enough reputation points.

So, here's the corrected version of Tuncay's answer (amending "TFormatSetting" missing an "s" and specified the format settings date separator):

```
function AnyStringToDate(fmt, dt: String) : TDateTime;
var
  fs : TFormatSettings;
Begin
  fs := TFormatSettings.Create;
  fs.DateSeparator := '-';
  fs.ShortDateFormat := fmt;

  result := StrToDateDef(dt, 0, fs);
End;
```

Identical to Tuncay's answer, AnyStringToDate can be used as follows:

```
mydate := AnyStringToDate('YYYY-MM-DD', '2015-01-20');
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix!

Comment: It doesn't work for strings that have format 'yyyymmdd' without the '-' separators :'(

Answer (score 5):

Without using any external library, you can do something like:

```
function AnyStringToDate(fmt, dt: String) : TDateTime;
var
  fs : TFormatSettings;
Begin
  fs := TFormatSettings.Create;
  fs.ShortDateFormat := fmt;

  result := StrToDateDef(dt, 0, fs);
End;
```

and then use it like:

```
  mydate := AnyStringToDate('YYYY-MM-DD', '2015-01-20');
```

I havent compiled this, but the idea simple.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [StrToDateFmt](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aStrToDateFmt) function of JvJCLUtils unit belonging to [JEDI Code Library](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/index.php?title=JEDI_Code_Library)

in your case :

```
Function InvFormatDatetime ( dateString :String; dateFormat :String ) : TDateTime;
begin
   Result := JvJCLUtils.StrToDateFmt ( dateFormat, dateString );
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check StrToDate and StrToDateTime ?

Comment: Gah!  I've been ninja'd! x.x  +1

Comment: @Liz, i knew these functions, and they not support the functionality wich i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late but just for interest sake, with Delphi XE6 onwards you can now do the following

```
uses
  System.DateUtils;
var
  dt: TDateTime;
begin
  dt := ISO8601ToDate('20190408');
end.
```

dt will now be 2019/04/08

Answer (score 0):

```
Function InvFormatDatetime (Cadena:String; Formato:String) : TDateTime;

Var
  PosD, PosM, PosY : Integer;
  sD, sM, sY       : String;

begin

  sd := '0';
  sm := '0';
  sy := '0';

  If Length(Cadena) = Length(Formato) Then
    Begin
      Formato := UpperCase(Formato);
      PosD := Pos('D',Formato);
      PosM := Pos('M',Formato);
      PosY := Pos('Y',Formato);

      sd := Copy(Cadena,PosD,2);
      sm := Copy(Cadena,PosM,2);

      if Length(Cadena) = 6 then
        begin
          sy := Copy(Cadena,PosY,2);
          if StrToInt(sy) > 50 then
            sy := '19'+sy
          else
            sy := '20'+sy;
        end
      else
        sy := Copy(Cadena,Posy,4);
    End;
  Result := EncodeDate(StrToInt(sY),
                       StrToInt(sM),
                       StrToInt(sD));
End;
```

greetings

Comment: This function assumes that the only day and month formats used are DD and MM, when they can in fact be between 1 and 4 characters long, and any format amy appear more than once. This code also ignores `TwoDigitYearCenturyWindow`.