# Is StrToDateTime broken in Delphi 11?

Tags: delphi, datetime-conversion, tdatetime

In Delphi 10.4 and older we could call `StrToDateTime` with custom format settings and the String would get parsed. In 11.3 this is not the case anymore.

I get the following exception:

> Project X.exe raised exception class EConvertError with message ''2023-05-12 12:11:10' is not a valid date and time'.

Demonstration of the problem:

```
procedure ConvertDate;
var
  lFormatSettings: TFormatSettings;
  lDate: TDateTime;
begin
  lFormatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create();
  lFormatSettings.DateSeparator := '-';
  lFormatSettings.TimeSeparator := ':';
  lFormatSettings.ShortDateFormat := 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss';

  lDate := StrToDateTime('2023-05-12 12:11:10', lFormatSettings);  // <-- EConvertError Exception
end;
```

Does someone know a workaround for this?

Comment: {This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3789628/62576) might be of use to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify only the date part in *ShortDateFormat*. The time part goes into *LongTimeFormat*.

This is what works (at least here):

```
  lFormatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create();
  lFormatSettings.DateSeparator := '-';
  lFormatSettings.TimeSeparator := ':';
  lFormatSettings.ShortDateFormat := 'yyyy-mm-dd';
  lFormatSettings.LongTimeFormat := 'hh:nn:ss';
```

Comment: I have already tried this. It doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Not sure what you tried, but I added the code working here.

Comment: `(Try)StrToDateTime()`, `(Try)StrToDate()`, and `(Try)StrToTime()` have always parsed a date using `ShortDateFormat` and `DateSeparator`, and parsed a time as fixed `hh[:mm[:ss[.zzz]]] [am|pm]` using the `TimeSeparator`,  `DecimalSeparator`, and `Time(AM|PM)String` only, they do not use either `ShortTimeFormat` or `LongTimeFormat` at all when parsing a time.  If parsing has recently stopped working, then that is a regression that needs to be [reported to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com)

Comment: "*they do not use either `ShortTimeFormat` or `LongTimeFormat` at all when parsing a time*" - however, when parsing a date (not a time), if `SysLocale.FarEast` is true and `ShortDateFormat` contains `'dddd'` then `ShortTimeFormat[1]` is checked for `['0'..'9']` and if so then any non-digit text following the date is skipped.

Comment: In fact, `ShortTimeFormat` (and `LongTimeFormat`) are not used for any parsing at all (except for the 1 condition mentioned above), they are used only for formatting date/time strings.

Comment: It may indeed be sufficient to set ShortDateFormat as shown and leave the time format as is.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: "If parsing has recently stopped working, then that is a regression that needs to be reported to Embarcadero".  Assuming that it's the exact same problem, it is and it was, and their answer was "We had "several" bug reports about "bad" checking of formats. So, we fixed this. Earlier or later we have to pay our debts ...".  See [RSP-35691](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-35691)

Comment: The effective point here is: It shouldn't have been working before.

Comment: @kkrajnc Per [RSP-35691](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-35691), have you tried using `ShortDateFormat = 'yyyy/mm/dd'` with `DateSeparator = '-'`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've tried now your suggestion and it works