# how I can convert str to datetime?

Tags: delphi, datetime, date

How I can convert "02 August 2012 18:53" to DateTime?

when I use StrToDate for convert it occur error 'Invalid Date format'

Comment: +1. This turns out to be a much more difficult question to answer than it appears at first. The only thing missing is info about the fact you're reading the value from a text file and what the encoding of that text file is, and it would be a really good question - all the other info is there. :-)

Comment: See also [Inverse function of FormatDateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2503460/576719).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a string to TDateTime based on an arbitrary format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786823/converting-a-string-to-tdatetime-based-on-an-arbitrary-format)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `VarToDateTime` (found in the `Variants` unit), which supports various time formats Delphi's RTL doesn't. (It's based on COM's date support routines like the ones used in various Microsoft products.) I tested with your supplied date, and it indeed converts it to a `TDateTime` properly. Tested on both Delphi 2007 and XE2.

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils, Variants;


var
  DT: TDateTime;
  TestDate: String;

begin
  TestDate := '02 August 2012 18:53';

  try
    DT := VarToDateTime(TestDate);
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Writeln(FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn', DT));
  Readln;
end.
```

More info in the current [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.VarToDateTime) , including another sample of use (link at the bottom of that page).

Note the function in `Variants` unit use the default user locale. If it is not 'US' the conversion from the above string might fail. In that case you would better call `VarDateFromStr` directly from `activex` unit specifying the US locale:

```
uses
  sysutils, activex, comobj;

var
  TestDate: String;
  DT: TDateTime;
begin
  try
    TestDate := '02 August 2012 18:53';
    OleCheck(VarDateFromStr(WideString(TestDate), $0409, 0, Double(DT)));
    Writeln(FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn', DT));
    Readln;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: but this function also have problem with this error message: 'could not convert variant of type (UnicodeString) into type (Date)'

Comment: Your question says nothing about Unicode, and I tested (as I just wrote to say and supply code for) in both Delphi 2007 (AnsiString) and XE2 (UnicodeString) versions. You gave no information that would lead anyone to think about Unicode issues here.

Comment: I changed my code and put the '02 August 2012 18:53' into AnsiString Variable, but now I have this error : 'could not convert variant of type (String) into type (Date)

Comment: @Virgoir, as I said. I **tested** the code above. You can copy and paste it into a new console application in your version of Delphi and test it yourself. It works. I can't tell you anything else, except to check the string itself. The code above works with both AnsiString and UnicodeString in Delphi 2007 and XE2. Just use a `String` variable like I did above (changed in my edit just now).

Comment: yes I know, but I need convert that string from a text file to TDateTime, and I never said that your code have a problem. I just looking for a solution for my problem. Thanks

Comment: Same error here ('Could not convert variant of type ..'). Maybe because 'VarDateFromStr' is eventually called with 'LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT'? Dunno..

Comment: @Sertac, Virgoir: I don't know what's happening here. It may be because I'm running a US locale; I just re-ran the app on an XP SP2 machine (first test was Win7 64) just to make sure, and it works fine there in both the D2007 and XE2 versions. ??? What encoding is the text file you're reading from, Virgoir?

Comment: @Ken - That's exactly it, VarToDateTime leads to a path that 'VarDateFromStr' is called with LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT. If the user locale is not US (or compatible), a type mismatch occurs. Mind if I edit your answer a little bit?

Comment: @Sertac - not at all. Help yourself. :-) Thanks for doing the research.

Comment: @Sertac, nice addition. Thanks in return. :-)