# SQL Query works in Workbench but get 'Could not convert variant type' error with the exact same query in Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, workbench

The exact error i'm getting is

> Could not convert variant of type (UnicodeString) into type(Date).

The variable I am using for the date is a string and I have to place quotation marks around it or else it returns null but when I put the quotation marks around it I get this error.

Here is my code for the SQL Query and the variable `TodaysDate`. (This code isn't copy and pasted due to it being on a different machine without internet capabilities so please ignore anything that might cause a compiling error)

```pascal
    if MidStr(DateToStr(Date),2,1) ='/' then
         TodaysDate := MidStr(DateToStr(Date),6,4) + '-' + '0' + 
         MidStr(DateToStr(Date),1,1) + '-' + MidStr(DateToStr(Date),3,2)
    else
      TodaysDate := MidStr(DateToStr(Date),7,4) + '-' 
      + MidStr(DateToStr(Date),1,2) + '-' + MidStr(DateToStr(Date),4,2);

   ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
   ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT tbl.emailAddress, tbljob.Time FROM '+
   'dbwindowwash.tblclient, dbwindowwash.tbljob, dbwindowash.tbljobclientworker '+
   'WHERE tbljobclientworker.jobID = tbljob.jobID AND '+
   'tbljobclientworker.clientID = tblclient.clientID AND tbljob.Date = ' +
   QuotedStr(TodaysDate));
   ADOQuery1.Open

   // More Code using the email addresses and time
```

Copy and pasted straight into the Workbench this query gives me all the data I want but in Delphi gives me and error and with no `QuotedStr()` it returns null in both Delphi and Workbench.

I have a similar query in my program elsewhere which uses the date as a string with `QuotedStr()` and it works fine so I have absolutely no idea what is wrong with this.

Comment: Delphi appears is unable to do the implicit conversion from string to date that Workbench does.  You'll have to cast the quotedStr using proper Delphi casting.  the reason it may work elsewhere is because you may be working with string data there; whereas here it's a date.  for example: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=StrToDateTime  `StrToDateTime('23/02/2075 12:34:56');` or similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782114/how-i-can-convert-str-to-datetime

Comment: Use parameters - not only to get rid of conversion/formatting issues, but also prevent sql-injection

Comment: You have enough rep to add a comment. You do not have to add an answer to reply to anything. Update/Edit your question if you have more details or add a comment

Comment: At the very least use this: TodaysDate := FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd',Date)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreeing with SirRufo's comment here.  The correct answer to "how do I do this?" is "don't do that; that's the wrong way to do it."

If you stick values directly into the query like that, hackers can find a way to [place things into your query that get interpreted as SQL commands.](http://xkcd.com/327/)  This is known as **SQL injection**, and it's been responsible for billions of dollars' worth of damage in the last few decades.  (Not exaggerating.)

The right way to do it is by cleanly separating your SQL code from your data, by using *parameters,* like so:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;

//: before an identifier specifies a parameter
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT tbl.emailAddress, tbljob.Time FROM '+
  'dbwindowwash.tblclient, dbwindowwash.tbljob, dbwindowash.tbljobclientworker '+
  'WHERE tbljobclientworker.jobID = tbljob.jobID AND '+
  'tbljobclientworker.clientID = tblclient.clientID AND tbljob.Date = :date';

//parse the query and find parameter declarations
ADOQuery1.Prepare;

//set a value for the parameter
ADOQuery1.ParamByName['date'].AsDateTime := TodaysDate;

ADOQuery1.Open
```

The exact syntax for how to set the value of a parameter may differ from one dataset type to another, but that should give you the basic idea.

Comment: Lol sorry about only accepting your answer now, forgot to do it way back when I asked the question, but a late thanks anyway for you answer and being the first person to teach me about SQL Injection, cause its cropped up in other projects I've done.

Comment: @user3562014: Glad I could help.  SQL is one of those unfortunate languages where it's simple and intuitive to do the wrong thing, and getting it right takes more work, plus education to even know about the problem in the first place.  The more people know about SQL Injection and how to avoid it, the better. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a date to work correctly in an SQL query don't go hobbying yourself but use the following format: yyyymmdd.

For instance april 3 2014 becomes: 20140403.

You do this easily with FormatDateTime, in your case:

```
TodaysDate := FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd', Date)
```

This date notation is iso compliant and you don't have to think about local settings anymore.