# Date formatting glitch occuring - probable causes, and likeliest ways to prevent or negate?

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer-9, delphi-7

I'm working with a Delphi 7 program written by my predecessor, and one of the things he was constantly doing in it is resetting the DateSeparator value and ShortDateFormat value.  (Separator is '/', format is 'YYYY-MM-DD'.)  The program in question is trying to check a set of records against a database, update them as needed, then write them out to a file for a handheld barcode scanner.  Additionally, it is possible to select a set of records and display them as a report, done by passing their key values off inside a ShellExec string to a php page that actually runs the report.

Normally, this program works correctly, with no problems.  However, on some machines (seems to be specific to Win7 boxes running IE9), if the reports are run first (opening IE from within the ShellExec call) the portion of the code that attempts to verify the records will end up with their dates screwed up - instead of appearing as YYYY-MM-DD as the Delphi ShortDateFormat calls specify, or as the M/d/yyyy of the Win7 default format, they'll appear in the output file as something screwy like 'ddyyyymm'.  (The code is stripping the separators before writing to the file.  The lack of them is expected.)

Given the weird conditions under which this problem occurs, I'm suspecting that something about opening IE9 is explicitly overwriting the program's attempt to reset the date format.  Has anyone ever heard of anything like this before?  And if so, what options do I have for resolving the issue?  I don't have the authority to demand an IE upgrade on every machine our client uses this program on, and I'm not sure that would actually solve the problem anyway.  I'm half afraid I'm going to have to reset the formats as the initial portion of every possible function and procedure in the program, and am seriously hoping there's something I can do that won't be so time-consuming and error-prone.

Comment: Please add some source code, but the answer seems to be: **Use parameters** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229732/sql-query-works-in-workbench-but-get-could-not-convert-variant-type-error-with (today is parameter day)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
Application . UpdateFormatSettings := false;
```

after

```
 Application.Initialize;
```

in the DPR file.

From time-to-time the operating system will issue a WM_WININICHANGE message to all applications, to say that some global parameter, such as the user's regional settings, have changed.  There are several things that can trigger this, usually it makes sense, but sometimes it can be a mystery.  When a Delphi application receives this message, it will re-initialize the format settings.  This is usually a good thing.  Imagine you have a clock application that displays the date and time every second using DateTimeToStr(Now).  The user goes into the Windows regional settings and changes their date format.  Windows issues the WM_WININICHANGE message and your program's settings are automatically updated.  The next time your clock display is updated, it will use the new correct settings.

But, if you are overriding the FormatSettings with application-specific values, this can be a big problem.  Suddenly the settings that you worked so hard to set precisely as needed are thrown away and replaced with the default settings.

You can prevent this by setting UpdateFormatSettings to false.

Your application depends on the FormatSettings being as you've set them.  And everything usually works perfectly.  My hypothesis is that something is happening on those machines that's triggering the WM_WININICHANGE message.