# TryStrToDate Fails with format mmm/yy

Tags: date, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I am trying to convert a string in the format of mmm/yy to a `TDateTime` using the `TryStrToDate` function. However it always seems to fail.

I create a format settings record and set the date separator and short date format. I set the long date format to show that the issue occurs whether l set short or long date format.

If l change the example to use dd/mm/yyyy and pass in 01/02/2017 then it succeeds so l believe the issue may be the format. I used the following link as a reference to create the format string

http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=formatdatetime

I have made a demo console app to show an example of what l am trying to do

```
uses
   System.SysUtils;

function ValidateDate(ADate: string): boolean;
var
    fs: TFormatSettings;
    DateTime: TDateTime;
begin
    fs := TFormatSettings.Create();
    fs.DateSeparator := '/';
    fs.ShortDateFormat := 'mmm/yy';
    fs.LongDateFormat := 'mmm/yy';

    result := true;
    if not TryStrToDate(ADate, DateTime, fs) then
        result := false;
end;

begin
    try
        if not ValidateDate('Oct/16') then
            WriteLn('Failed to convert')
    except
        on E: Exception do
            Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
    end;
end.
```

l would appreciate any ideas as to why this fails

Comment: Don't use Delphibasics. Use the official documentation. And your setting of result is odd. Use `result := TryStrToDate(...)`

Comment: Perhaps [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11782114/62576) (particularly the answer I wrote) can help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following advice from David l have created a function that will convert months from the string ie Jan to 01 and then calls TryStrToDate to get the converted date. If the format string does not contain a day then it will default to 01

```
function ParseDate(ADate: string; AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings): TDateTime;
var
    DateData, FormatData: TStringList;
    Month, Day, Year: string;
    ConvertedDate: Double;
    i: integer;

    function ConvertMonth(AMonth: string; ALongMonth: boolean = false): string;
    var
        i: integer;
    begin
        Result := '-1'; // default to invalid month
        if ALongMonth then
        begin
            for i := 1 to high(AFormatSettings.LongMonthNames) do
            begin
                if AFormatSettings.LongMonthNames[i] = AMonth then
                begin
                    Result := inttostr(i); // MonthArray starts at index 1 which matches the month
                    break;
                end;
            end;
        end
        else
        begin
            for i := 1 to high(AFormatSettings.ShortMonthNames) do
            begin
                if AFormatSettings.ShortMonthNames[i] = AMonth then
                begin
                    Result := inttostr(i); // MonthArray starts at index 1 which matches the month
                    break;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;
begin
    DateData := TStringList.Create();
    FormatData := TStringList.Create();
    try
        DateData.Delimiter := AFormatSettings.DateSeparator;
        DateData.StrictDelimiter := true;
        DateData.DelimitedText := ADate;

        FormatData.Delimiter := AFormatSettings.DateSeparator;
        FormatData.StrictDelimiter := true;
        FormatData.DelimitedText := AFormatSettings.ShortDateFormat;

        Day := '01';
        Month := '01';
        Year := '01';

        for i := 0 to FormatData.Count - 1 do
        begin
            if FormatData[i].IndexOf('d') <> -1 then
                Day := DateData[i]
            else if FormatData[i].IndexOf('m') <> -1 then
            begin
                if FormatData[i] = 'mmm' then
                    Month := ConvertMonth(DateData[i])
                else if FormatData[i] = 'mmmm' then
                    Month := ConvertMonth(DateData[i], true)
                else
                    Month := DateData[i]
            end
            else if FormatData[i].IndexOf('y') <> -1 then
                Year := DateData[i]
        end;

        ADate := Day + AFormatSettings.DateSeparator + Month + AFormatSettings.DateSeparator + Year;

        AFormatSettings.ShortDateFormat := 'dd' + AFormatSettings.DateSeparator + 'mm' + AFormatSettings.DateSeparator + 'yyyy';
        TryStrToDate(ADate, Result, AFormatSettings);
    finally
        DateData.free();
        FormatData.free();
    end;
end;
```

If any one can see any improvements or optimisations please let me know.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked. Furthermore this code is really poor.

Comment: How would you have programmed it? I have allowed passing in a date string and then a format settings to state what format that date string is in. Which l then convert to a format that trystrtodate will accept

Comment: I don't think that's really relevant to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 7):

Your format strings are not valid. These format strings must encode day, month and year. You omit day which is not permitted.

The string which you supply for conversion is allowed to omit the year. In that case the current year is assumed.

If you wish to convert these strings to just months and year, then include a fake day, e.g. 1,  in the strings that you pass to `TryStrToDate`. Then use `DecodeDate` to obtain numeric values for month and year, ignoring the day.

So, use `'d/mmm/yy'` as the format and pass `'1/' + ADate` as the string to be converted.

Note also that it is the short date string format that is used to convert from string to date, so that is the only one you need to set.

Finally, this is such a simple format you could quite easily parse it directly.

**Update**

As you have observed, and stated in the comments, the RTL functionality is implemented with a call to `ScanDate` which only supports numeric month formats. So the entire approach you have attempted is, sadly, doomed to failure. Even if you fix the issues that I have identified.

My advice is to simply parse the string yourself, since its format is so very simple.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your help. Implementing your changes and looking at the source for TryStrToDate it looks like it trys to call scannumber on 'mmm' so in this case Oct which of course fails. Would this mean l can't use mmm in the format? or am l missing something?

Comment: Gah, I had not realised that. I think you are right, StrToDate and friends only support numeric months. I think you'll be best off parsing this yourself. Check that there is exactly one `/` character, split on that character, and parse the two parts.